# Combination of roles in Episerver

Tags: roles, episerver, episerver-6-r2

I have a site where our customers log in to see their own data. Each customer must only see their own data (of course), and different users will have access to different pages within one customer. In addition - the editors must see all data.

I want to set up the access rights based on roles to determine which customer that the user is member of, and what pages the user can access.

**Groups:**

- Customer1Role
- Customer2Role
- TicketViewerRole
- ChangeRequestRole

**Users:**

- Cust1_LowLevelUser. **Roles**: *Customer1Role, TicketViewerRole*
- Cust1_HighLevelUser **Roles**: *Customer1Role, TicketViewRole, ChangeRequestRole*
- Cust2_LowLevelUser. **Roles**: *Customer2Role, TicketViewerRole*
- Cust2_HighLevelUser **Roles**: *Customer2Role, TicketViewRole, ChangeRequestRole*

**Page structure**

We have created a page tree where each customer has its own "root page" with access only to their respective role. Below that node we create instances of the data specific pages, which have their access rights based on user roles as well as the customer role.

```
Customer1 (Customer1Role)
  |--TicketsForCust1 (Customer1Role, TicketViewerRole)
  |--ChangeRequestsForCust1 (Customer1Role, ChangeRequestRole)
Customer2 (Customer2Role)
  |--TicketsForCust2 (Customer2Role, TicketViewerRole)
  |--ChangeRequestsForCust2 (Customer2Role, ChangeRequestRole)
```

**Burning question:**

How do we prevent user **Cust2_HighLevelUser** from seeing `ChangeRequestsForCust1`?

EPiServer only checks if any role is sufficient for granting access, and since the user belongs to **ChangeRequestRole**, they will be granted access, regardless of the customer specific role. Is it possible to make EPiServer check BOTH the customer role, and the page role?

Or do I have to look at this from another view? Please let me know if you have run into this and solved it in another way.

Sorry, long post, but hopefully I get my point across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Deny flag in the access rights model so you need to code it yourself with that role structure.

Add code to your template base class that denies access and for the PageTree control you can do something like this:

```
protected void NavSubPageTreeFilter(object sender, EPiServer.Filters.FilterEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = e.Pages.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        PageData pd = e.Pages[i];

        if (yourUser.IsInRole("blabla") && ... etc)
        {
            e.Pages.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any suggestion on how to structure the roles differently to improve the solution?

Comment: You need a "Customer1TicketViewerRole". If you don't want to create it by hand, then possibly by adding your own RoleProvider. That way you could assemble a "dynamic" role called "Customer1TicketViewerRole" and set page permissions for that one.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, Johan. We have now implemented a solution where we add a dynamic property on the parent page that defines which customer role you must be in to view its children. We really wanted to stay away from customer specific roles, due to maintenance.